# Migrate pictures and data from a Document Library to a Picture Library?

Tags: migration, picture-library

I have a SharePoint Document Library containing about 1500 pictures and about 15 columns of metadata created years ago, and I have a new requirement that requires the functionality of a Picture Library.  Is there a way to migrate the 1500 pictures and their metadata to a Picture Library?  Is manual data entry the only way to accomplish this?  I hope not.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have those 15 meta data columns available in the Pic Library. And does it the meta data fields have the same name?

Comment: Using content and structure to copy the files to the new library should create and copy all the same metadata fields over. If this works to your liking, then you can use content and structure to move the files.

Comment: Revised again as I seem to be narrowing down the problem.  It is occurring when trying to copy anything from one library to another, even if they are identical structurally.  When using the "Content and Structure" page to move my files from one library to another,  I'm getting the following error:  "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."  I'm now researching based on this latest finding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer to my question was answered by Eric. Data can be moved from one library to another simply by using Content and Structure in Site Settings.

NOTE:  The error I mentioned in my comments is still occurring, but only on my Office 365 site.  I will research that as a separate issue.

NOTE:  The "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature needs to be turned on before the Content and Structure settings are available.